# Has this server been compromised?

Tags: linux, centos, vps, spam, smtp

A friend is running a VPS (CentOS)

His business partner was the sysadmin but has left him high and dry to look after the system.  So, I've been asked to help out in fixing an apparent spam problem.  His IP address got blacklisted for unsolicited mail.  I'm not sure where to look for a problem, but I started with netstat to see what open connections were running.  It looks to me like he has remote hosts connected to his SMTP server.  Here's the output:

```
    Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State      
tcp        0      0 78.153.208.195:imap         86-40-60-183-dynamic.:10029 ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 78.153.208.195:imap         86-40-60-183-dynamic.:10010 ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      1 78.153.208.195:35563        news.avanport.pt:smtp       SYN_SENT    
tcp        0      0 78.153.208.195:35559        vip-us-br-mx.terra.com:smtp TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 78.153.208.195:35560        vip-us-br-mx.terra.com:smtp TIME_WAIT   
tcp        1      1 78.153.208.195:imaps        86-40-60-183-dynamic.:11647 CLOSING     
tcp        1      1 78.153.208.195:imaps        86-40-60-183-dynamic.:11645 CLOSING     
tcp        0      0 78.153.208.195:35562        mx.a.locaweb.com.br:smtp    TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 78.153.208.195:35561        mx.a.locaweb.com.br:smtp    TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 78.153.208.195:imap         86-41-8-64-dynamic.b-:49446 ESTABLISHED
```

Does this indicate that his server may be acting as an open relay?  Mail should only be outgoing from localhost.

Apologies for my lack of knowledge but I don't work on linux in my day job.

---

**EDIT:**
Here's some output from `/var/log/maillog` which looks like it may be the result of spam.  If it appears to be the case to others, where should I look next to investigate a root cause?  I put the server IP through www.checkor.com and it came back clean.

```
Jun 29 00:02:13 vps-1001108-595 qmail: 1309302133.721674 status: local 0/10 remote 9/20
Jun 29 00:02:13 vps-1001108-595 qmail: 1309302133.886182 delivery 74116: deferral: 200.147.36.15_does_not_like_recipient./Remote_host_said:_450_4.7.1_Client_host_rejected:_cannot_find_your_hostname,_[78.153.208.195]/Giving_up_on_200.147.36.15./
Jun 29 00:02:13 vps-1001108-595 qmail: 1309302133.886255 status: local 0/10 remote 8/20
Jun 29 00:02:13 vps-1001108-595 qmail: 1309302133.898266 delivery 74115: deferral: 187.31.0.11_does_not_like_recipient./Remote_host_said:_450_4.7.1_Client_host_rejected:_cannot_find_your_hostname,_[78.153.208.195]/Giving_up_on_187.31.0.11./
Jun 29 00:02:13 vps-1001108-595 qmail: 1309302133.898327 status: local 0/10 remote 7/20
Jun 29 00:02:14 vps-1001108-595 qmail: 1309302134.137833 delivery 74111: deferral: Sorry,_I_wasn't_able_to_establish_an_SMTP_connection._(#4.4.1)/
Jun 29 00:02:14 vps-1001108-595 qmail: 1309302134.137914 status: local 0/10 remote 6/20
Jun 29 00:02:19 vps-1001108-595 qmail: 1309302139.903536 delivery 74000: failure: 209.85.143.27_failed_after_I_sent_the_message./Remote_host_said:_550-5.7.1_[78.153.208.195_______1]_Our_system_has_detected_an_unusual_rate_of/550-5.7.1_unsolicited_mail_originating_from_your_IP_address._To_protect_our/550-5.7.1_users_from_spam,_mail_sent_from_your_IP_address_has_been_blocked./550-5.7.1_Please_visit_http://www.google.com/mail/help/bulk_mail.html_to_review/550_5.7.1_our_Bulk_Email_Senders_Guidelines._e25si1385223wes.137/
Jun 29 00:02:19 vps-1001108-595 qmail: 1309302139.903606 status: local 0/10 remote 5/20
Jun 29 00:02:19 vps-1001108-595 qmail-queue-handlers[15501]: Handlers Filter before-queue for qmail started ...
```

**EDIT #2**
Here's the output of `netstat -p` with the `imap` and `imaps` lines removed.  I also removed my own `ssh` session

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      1 78.153.208.195:40076        any-in-2015.1e100.net:smtp  SYN_SENT    24096/qmail-remote. 
tcp        0      1 78.153.208.195:40077        any-in-2015.1e100.net:smtp  SYN_SENT    24097/qmail-remote. 
udp        0      0 78.153.208.195:48515        125.64.11.158:4225          ESTABLISHED 20435/httpd
```

**EDIT**
As it turns out, the server had been hacked due to a vulnerability in OSCommerce and a number of PHP scripts were being run by remote clients to send mail.  This was due to the security settings of 777 on the `/var/www/vhosts/<domain-name>/httpdocs/images` directory

Comment: I would suggest your first priority is to ensure the system isn't an open relay. The spam may not have originated on this system.

Comment: That must not be spam at all. If the mailserver is just not configured at the state of *RFC5321* you may get blacklisted too. There is no **PTR** set for the host, and maybe a invalid HELO to. Some html only mails, as default today, and we have a new blacklist entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This,

```
tcp        0      0 78.153.208.195:imap         86-40-60-183-dynamic.:10029
```

is an external connection using IMAP to read mail from a mailbox on your server.

This,

```
tcp        0      1 78.153.208.195:35563        news.avanport.pt:smtp       SYN_SENT
```

is your server sending outbound SMTP mail to news.avanport.pt

Without knowing more about what it is and is not supposed to be doing, neither of those things are initially suspicious.

You will need to use mailqueue, check out /var/log/mail* and the mail config to work out if it's right or not, or provide more info in the question.

Comment: Thanks EightBitTony, I added some log messages to the question.

Comment: Rerun your netstat command with the `-p` flag as root, this will show the process names involved.  You can leave off the imap/imaps lines, but show the outgoing smtp connections.  Are there any webpages on the server that might have an email form that could be used to send emails to random people?

Comment: What is this server *supposed* to be doing? Is it a company mailserver, or do you have clients using it for mail? One thing I'd do as a sysadmin is sniff the packets on port 25 and see what some of the text of the emails are. It should be fairly obvious if they're spam.

Comment: Since you're running qmail, search the Googles for qmail open relay and use results to check what your qmail config is. If you find that you have it totally screwy for what clients it's allowing to connect, *close them*. See if that's what is causing the relaying.

Comment: There are also remote sites that you can Googles for that will tell you after a quick test if your system is allowing mail as an open relay. I get suspicious that some of them will blacklist you if they find it open, but sounds like that ship has already sailed.

Comment: DerfK - I added the `-p` option to `netstat` and appended the output to the question.

Comment: Bart - The server just hosts a few small websites, a couple of databases and the mail accounts belonging to those sites.  I checked on http://www.checkor.com/ to see if it had an open relay but it appears OK.  I will look for other testing sites and also for any misconfiguration of qmail.  Thanks

Comment: @Griffo: I'd definitely sniff the network traffic, as long as it's allowed in your policies for your clients, restricted to port 25 so you can examine the text. If the websites weren't secured down it's possible someone compromised one or more of them with a buffer overflow or something similar.

Comment: Also, set up a system to run Nessus (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nessus_%28software%29) or a similar application (also in the article) to pen-test your server. See if they uncover known vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your system get compromised, but:

- you should set a valid reverse DNS entry if you want to send mail, thats was the messages in the maillog belongs to

`Jun 29 00:02:13 vps-1001108-595 qmail: 1309302133.886182 delivery 74116: deferral: 200.147.36.15_does_not_like_recipient./Remote_host_said:_450_4.7.1_Client_host_rejected:_cannot_find_your_hostname,_[78.153.208.195]/Giving_up_on_200.147.36.15./`

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I'll look into that too.  Jeez, whoever administered this server must have been lazy!